# Initialising flask environment variable issues

Tags: flask

I am trying to create a an application using Flask. I have done this before successfully, however, I am not sure why this is not working this time. Everything seems to be in the right order. I have searched for answers, however, I still can't determine what's going wrong as everything seems logical to me? Yet, it is still going wrong?

```
    ZXM934/
      app/
        __innit__.py
        views.py
      venv/
      run.py
```

The following are each files contents:

```
run.py
```

```
    # Importing app object which was created in __innit__.py file into app.py
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
__innit__.py
```

```
    # This class will ultimately bring our entire application together.

from flask import Flask

# Creating Flask app.
app = Flask(__name__)

# Importing views file to avoid circular import.
from app import views
```

```
view.py
```

```
    # This class represents the UI of our website. 

# Importing app directory. As __innit__.py file is apart of this directory, 
# this import treats it as a package. 
from app import app

@app.route("/")
def public_home():
    return "Homepage"

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return "<h1 style='color: red'>Login</h1>"
```

I set the environment variables as following within the console:

```
export FLASK_APP=run.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

I then run the following command:

```
flask run
```

The following error occurs:

```
    flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "run", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zahidmalik-ramzan/Desktop/zxm934/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/zahidmalik-ramzan/Desktop/zxm934/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (unknown location)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the file name `__innit__.py`.

For python to understand that a folder is an actual package within your project structure you need a special file inside, i.e. `__init.py__` **ps: no double n**.

> A regular package is typically implemented as a directory containing an __init__.py file. When a regular package is imported, this __init__.py file is implicitly executed, and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace.

Conclusion: change your `__innit.py__` to `__init.py__`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, plus the spelling error. I wouldn't have spotted that myself for a while. It all works. I'll be sure to double check small errors such as this for any future problems similar to this.